# How do I use printf() in java to print out a table?

Tags: java, arraylist, printf

I'm trying to print out a table, in which each column is a different arraylist, where each element then goes down a line.  So something like this:

```
Name:    Age:    Gender:
Bob        18      Male
Mary       25      Female
```

And so on..
How would I format this with the printf() statement?

Comment: Couldn't you just use two `for loops` and display each element?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: lel. I knew about it, but don't somehow the `C`'s printf is only thing came to my mind. But oh well.... everyone does mistakes :p

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html).  `String.format` and `printf` share the same formatting rules

So, something like...

```
System.out.printf("%15s", "Name:");
System.out.printf("%4s", "Age:");
System.out.printf("%17s:%n", "Gender:");
```

will generate something like...

```
Name:          Age:          Gender:
```

Now, I've deliberatly broken down the example into three lines, but you could use a single line like `System.out.printf("%-15s%-4s%17s%n", "Name:", "Age:", "Gender:");` instead.

The important thing here is number between the `%` and `s`, `%15s`, which allows the formatter to fill out the remaining space with up to 15 spaces (for `Name:` that will add 10 more spaces), this will become obvious with the next example...

Next we need to format the data, for example...

```
String name = "Bob";
int age = 18;
String gender = "Male";
System.out.printf("%-15s", name);
System.out.printf("%4d", age);
System.out.printf("%17s%n", gender);

name = "Mary";
age = 25;
gender = "Female";
System.out.printf("%-15s", name);
System.out.printf("%4d", age);
System.out.printf("%17s%n", gender);
```

Note, that each column is using the same spacing!  This is important!

Altogether, this will print out...

```
Name:          Age:          Gender:
Bob              18             Male
Mary             25           Female
```

Also see [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more details about the format specifers

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("Name: %s\nAge: %d\nGender: %s\n", name, age, gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't call several times the printf, instead use StringBuilder wich allows you to create a dynamic String, after the String is complete then print it.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 2;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(rows * columns * 36);
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-15s%-4s%17s\n", "Name:", "Age:", "Gender:"));
        stringBuilder.append('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < rows ; ++i ) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%-15s%4d%17s\n", "column value",18,"Male"));
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```