# Print formatting in Java, hard left column, printing full statements

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I am not particularly familiar with formatting printing, and I am trying to print information about several shapes. The code I have right now is as follows:

```
System.out.printf("Box volume: %.2f cu ft       Box density: %.2f lbs. / cu ft\n\n", userBox.calculateVolume(), userBox.calculateDensity());        
System.out.printf("Cone volume: %.2f cu ft       Cone density: %.2f lbs. / cu ft\n\n", userCone.calculateVolume(), userCone.calculateDensity());        
System.out.printf("Cylinder volume: %.2f cu ft       Cylinder density: %.2f lbs. / cu ft\n\n", userCylinder.calculateVolume(), userCylinder.calculateDensity());        
System.out.printf("Sphere volume: %.2f cu ft       Sphere density: %.2f lbs. / cu ft\n\n", userSphere.calculateVolume(), userSphere.calculateDensity());
```

The gaps, however, are just spaces, and I am trying format it such that the volume column is left aligned, as well as the density column. I have read a little bit and using the "-" flag with printf(), however the examples I see are simply printing columns of values, not full statements as I have here, which is what separates it from questions like [How do I use printf() in java to print out a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124041/how-do-i-use-printf-in-java-to-print-out-a-table). Additionally, my class has not addressed the Formatter API so I would like to do so solely with printf().

I should also address that my Professor is particular about how he expects the formatting, so I am not able to just remove the text and put it as a header in a line above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "*Unfortunately I also do not know how to format the questions on Stack Overflow, so sorry for the ugly formatting.*" -- don't apologize, but instead read the site resources, such as the [ask] link and the [help section on how to format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that its readable. Then please [edit] your question to fix the formatting issues. And yes, please show your current code and data.

Comment: This [printf tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) may be of use to you as well as the [java.util.Formatter API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which uses a syntax same as printf.

Comment: Remove all the spaces in your printf code, except for single spaces, and instead use printf width specifiers, as well explained in the duplicates and the tutorials linked to above. Also, remove "Box volume:" and "Box density:" from the printf String and instead use that as a table heading, as part of the String at the top of your columns.